# Múltipla seleção não funciona no IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

Fiz um post em como com uma escolha, selecionar todos os itens. Recebi uma resposta, que resolveu. bem, resolveu apenas no Chrome, mas no IE não funciona. Como a pergunta mudou a "direção", então resolvi fazer um outro post. Inclui outras versões do jquery e mesmo assim não funcionou.
Esse é o código do meu select(html).

```
<tr>
                                <td width="10%" class="label_right">Autorização Prévia: &nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="label_left">
                                    <select id="ddl_autorizacaoprevia" multiple="multiple" >
                                        <option value="0">TODAS AS AUTORIZAÇÕES</option>
                                        <option value="T">TÉCNICA / ADMINISTRATIVA</option>
                                        <option value="A">SISTÊMICA</option>
                                        <option value="N">NÃO PRECISA</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Esse é o jquery que faz a seleção de todos os itens em um único clique:

```
$('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option').click(function () {

                var that = $(this);
                if (that.val() == 0) {
                    $('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option').each(function () {
                        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option').each(function () {
                        $(that).removeAttr('selected');
                    });
                    $(that).attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
            });
```

Então, esse código funciona bem no Chrome, mas não funciona no IE. O que pode ser? Só funciona com Ctrl+Clique, aí consigo selecionar todos, mas somente ao clicar o primeiro índice(índice = 0), aí não seleciona todos os itens, mas no Chrome funciona e o browser homologado pela empresa é o IE e não chrome, logo tenho que fazer funcionar no IE.

Comment: Segundo o que descreveu e baseado no código que postou, é esse o comportamento lógico que deve ocorrer. Quando clica num valor que não seja o ZERO, desmarca todos os outros e marca somente o que está "clicado". Está confuso na sua descrição sobre o que realmente não funciona ou qual o comportamento que deseja.

Comment: Ok, o que eu quero dizer que esse comportamento só funciona no Google Chrome. No IE não funciona. O código é funcional, só não no IE.

Comment: Se eu faço uma pergunta, querendo duas resposta, recebo downvote e um conselho a abrir outro post. Aí abro outro post e recebo downvote do mesmo jeito, porque parece ser uma pergunta repetida, por usar o mesmo código, porem com pergunta diferente. Queria entender.

Comment: Nessa linha `$('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option').each(function () ` se eu removo o option, consigo fazer a seleção múltipla, mas apenas se não houver nenhum selecionado. Caso eu selecione algum e depois clico no Item de índice 0, aí não funciona mais. Mas se recarrego a página(deseleciono tudo), dessa forma funciona. Entendi que o IE não "gosta" do option.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

acho que não precisava de tudo isso, faça o teste com esse código:

```
$('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option:first-child').click(function () {
    $('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option').each(function () {
         $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
});
```

Veja este exemplo aqui: 
https://jsfiddle.net/1vwb5nxp/

**EDIT**

Fiz uma implementação em javascript puro pra ver se resolve o seu problema, segue o código:

```
function qs(q) {
   return document.querySelector(q);
}
function qsa(q) {
   return document.querySelectorAll(q);
}
qs("#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option:first-child").onclick = function (ev) {
    var todos = qsa('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option');
    Array.prototype.slice.call(todos).forEach(function (e) {
        e.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    });
}
```

Exemplo do código: https://jsfiddle.net/kws9vrzp/

**EDIT 2**

Outra opção para ver se funciona no IE:

Código HTML (note que tirei o atributo multiple e coloquei o atributo size):

```
<tr>
                            <td width="10%" class="label_right">Autorização Prévia: &nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="label_left">
                                <select id="ddl_autorizacaoprevia" size=4 >
                                    <option value="0">TODAS AS AUTORIZAÇÕES</option>
                                    <option value="T">TÉCNICA / ADMINISTRATIVA</option>
                                    <option value="A">SISTÊMICA</option>
                                    <option value="N">NÃO PRECISA</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Javascript - Note que eu atribuo o multiple por aqui:

```
function qs(q) {
   return document.querySelector(q);
}
function qsa(q) {
   return document.querySelectorAll(q);
}

qs("#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option:first-child").onclick = function(){
   var select = qs("#ddl_autorizacaoprevia");
   var tamanho = select.length;
   select.multiple=true;
   select.focus();
   for(var i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
      select.options[i].selected=true
   }
}
```

Exemplo pode ser visto funcional aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Ls77e84e/

**EDIT 3**

Fiz algumas adaptações, mas foi a maneira que consegui fazer pegar o que foi pedido no Internet Explorer, veja se interessa:

```
<tr>
    <td width="10%" class="label_right">Autorização Prévia: &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="label_left">
        <select id="ddl_autorizacaoprevia" size=4 >
            <option value="T">TÉCNICA / ADMINISTRATIVA</option>
            <option value="A">SISTÊMICA</option>
            <option value="N">NÃO PRECISA</option>
        </select>
        <input id='selecionarTudo' type="checkbox"> TODAS AS AUTORIZAÇÕES
        </td>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
function gi (q) {
        return document.getElementById(q);
    }
    gi("selecionarTudo").onclick = function () {
        var el = this;
        var select = gi("ddl_autorizacaoprevia");
        var tamanho = select.length;
        if(this.checked == true){
            select.multiple = true;
            // select.focus();
            for(var i=0;i < tamanho;i++){
                select.options[i].selected = true;
            }
    //Caso ache válido pode descomentar essa linha;
            //select.disabled = true; 
        } else{
            select.multiple = false;
            select.disabled = false;
            for(var i=1;i < tamanho;i++){
                select.options[i].selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yjqgq37L/

Comment: Guilherme Lopes, abri o seu fiddle no IE e não funcionou. Experimente abri-lo no IE e veja se funciona? Comigo aqui não funfou.

Comment: Estou sem o IE para testar aqui, veja o EDIT para ver se resolve.

Comment: Guilherme, continua não funcionando no IE. Na empresa em que estou, só interessa o IE. Não funcionou mesmo. Li que o IE tem problemas com o Option do Select. E parece que procede essa informação.

Comment: Qual é a versão do IE que interessa?

Comment: A minha aqui é a 11.0.24(atualizada). Versões anteriores também usam. O site é usado por mais 1.000 usuários da empresa, em todo o Brasil. Não tenho como te informar, mas o IE é o único navegador homologado, logo pode ser qualquer versão. Esses testes foram feitos na versão citada.

Comment: Fiz uma adaptação nessa última edição e funcionou, caso ajude, está ai.

Comment: Valeu mesmo pela ajuda. Não é isso. Estamos conversando com a área de negócio da empresa e apresentando uma outra solução. Espero que eles aceitem, mas mesmo assim, eu agradeço, Guilherme, pela ajuda. Essa última, com um checkbox fora, está fora do escopo.